# Change docker process owner on mac os

Tags: docker, macos

I have a « user1 » account on a mac os system.
I have install docker from official site download with this user1 account.

I do not remember exactly but mac os asked me an admin user account authentification during docker installation.

There is something strange : if i log on my mac with an admin account, i cannot see all users running containers with « docker ps -a » command.

And if i type « ps aux | grep docker » in my terminal i can see docker server is runned as « user1 ». How can i change this user ?

Thanks

Comment: Docker on MacOS runs a hidden Linux VM; you can't directly see container processes from the host.  In any case it doesn't usually matter what user ID the container process runs as, with specific caveats around shared files, user-ID remapping, and a preference to avoid the root user.

Comment: Thanks is there a way to change the user ID (if i want to change it to user2 for example)